# Remove duration limit for low quality video capture intent

Tags: android, video, android-intent, video-capture, mediastore

I would like to record a video by using just an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

It needs to be a low quality so I use: `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);`
which works fine. The problem is that it gives me a limit of 23 seconds. Afterwards it stops recording. This limit is displayed on UI like this 00:00 / 00:23 and once it reaches that time it stops. This limit doesn't occur on high quality video settings. I tried to increase limit by setting:

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit",50);
```

But it doesn't affect it at all. I can give it smaller number than 23 seconds or I can give it higher with no effect. I also tried to increase size of the file with the same result.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 1000000);
```

These settings work for video high quality but not for video low quality. Does anyone have solution for it? Ideally video shouldn't have any duration limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that it gives me a limit of 23 seconds.

That is the way whatever app you are using to record the video implemented it. There is no requirement that all video apps implement such a limit, or that the limit be 23 seconds.

> Does anyone have solution for it? Ideally video shouldn't have any duration limit.

Record the video yourself using `Camera` and `MediaRecorder`. The developers of the worlds' camera apps are welcome to implement `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` however they want. If you need more control than that, you have to record it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will do as you suggest.